# Auto Populate Lat/Long ArcGIS Collector

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, arcgis-10.4, arcgis-collector

Is there a way to auto populate a Lat and Long field in a feature service in ArcGIS online. I have the newest version of collector and 10.4.1 ArcGIS. I'm pretty new to the online aspect of GIS so a walk-through would be very helpful.

Comment: I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  This earlier Q&A may be relevant: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/197784/115

Comment: is the Feature Layer hosted in AOL? if it is I dont think so

Comment: This is do-able with some python to update XY fields, set to run as a scheduled task against the hosted feature service.